# Static Reprompts (actions on NO_INPUT)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Currently, I am writing the code in fulfilment to achieve the `No_Input response`. I have written some code, it doesn't give the expected response for me. And also, I like to know is there any wrong coding in my fulfilment?. Give me some guidance.

```
  const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
  const NO_INPUT_PROMPTS = ['Would you like to answer the question?'];

  function ask(conv, inputPrompt, noInputPrompts) {
    conv.data.lastPrompt = inputPrompt;
    conv.data.lastNoInputPrompts = noInputPrompts;
    conv.noInputs = noInputPrompts
    conv.ask(inputPrompt);
  }

  app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
    let message = "Hello what's your favourite color";
    ask(conv,message,NO_INPUT_PROMPTS);
  })
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the expected response, and what are you getting?

Comment: I am not able to get anything and i don't know how exactly to do that Static NO_INPUT prompts as well. Help me to solve it.

Comment: I am trying to achieve that, STatic NO_INPUT prompts in my chatbot